# SpringBoot Localizing error messages in BindingResult

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, localization, thymeleaf

I'm trying to figure out how to localize error messages in spring boot. An ideal way would be to set the localized message names in errors like this:

```
@RequestMapping
public ModelAndView index(@Valid SomeDto dto, BindingResult result) {
    //...
    result.addError(new FieldError("field1","messages.field1.error1"));
    //...
}

//...

public class SomeDto {

    @Size(min = 3, message = "messages.field.error2")
    private String field1;
}
```

And then either process the fields in a response filter, or somehow parse the messages in thymeleaf template.

Comment: @Alex I don't see anything helpful in this article. Please note that localization setup is not an issue

Comment: You are right, I misunderstood your question!

Comment: That should already work out of the box. The `FieldError` is a `DefaultMessageSourceResolvable` which will be passed to the configured `MessageSource`. The only thing you need to do is make sure the error code `messages.field1.error1` is available in your `messages_[locale].properties`. If that doesn't work out-of-the-box your setup is flawed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out a way in thymeleaf:

```
<div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('field1')}"
     th:each="e : ${#fields.errors('field1')}" th:text="#{${e}}" >
</div>
```

However it's probably not the most elegant way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

"However it's probably not the most elegant way to do it."

Actually, you are quite close to "elegant way". Instead of: `th:text="#{${e}}"` just use `th:text="${e}"`. But of course, that will not display localized message. To display localized message you will add this in your `messages_en.properties` (or whatever your locale is) file:

```
Size.someDto.field1=Field has to contain at least {2} characters.
```

So, the pattern is basically: Name of validation annotation followed by name of model attribute instance which is followed by name of field. `{2}` stands for `min` annotation property value while `{1}` stands for `max`. And it will display localized message "out of box".

P.S. You don't need this line:

```
result.addError(new FieldError("field1","messages.field1.error1"));
```

Comment: I added `result.addError(new FieldError("field1","messages.field1.error1"));` to show that I also need to handle some errors manually, and display locale messages the same way. How do I use this pattern to display errors from controller validation?